# What happens when 4-byte mov is used to load multiple words?

Tags: assembly, x86, endianness

I have the following code (using AT&T syntax for x86):

```
x: .word 1
y: .word 0
z: .word 2
...
mov x, %eax # eax = 0x1
```

How is `x` moved into `%eax`?

I know that `mov` moves 4 bytes because the destination is 4-byte `%eax`, so an `l` suffix is optional.

I know `x`, `y`, and `z` are stored next to each other in memory since I put those source lines together in the same section, so I expect it would by something like this:

```
x       y       z
|       |       |
00 01 | 00 00 | 00 02
```

And mov will take the first 4 bytes: `00 01 00 00`. So, I expected eax to have in reverse order the first 4 bytes since x86 uses little endian encoding -> eax=`0x00 00 01 00` which is not the `0x1` I get from actually trying it.  (e.g. in GDB, with `print /x $eax` after single-stepping past the `mov`.)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: `x` is `01 00` not `00 01` since, as you say, x86 is little endian.

Comment: You're sort of mixing up endianess with an example that provides 16-bit data and 32-bit data movement, so the analysis is necessarily technical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Also, x, y, z I know that they are stored next to each other in memory, so I expect it would by something like this:

> ```
> x       y       z
> |       |       |
> 00 01 | 00 00 | 00 02
> ```

The order of these bytes is wrong!
Being little endian the assembler stored the values like:

```
x       y       z
|       |       |
01 00 | 00 00 | 02 00
```

Taking a full dword at *X* therefore finds 01 00 00 00 which equals 00000001h.

---

> With that order, mov will take the first 4 bytes from right to left? Like dcba? 01 (a) 00 (b) | 00 (c) 00 (d)

If *you* like to think about it that way. Executing a dword-sized `mov`, the CPU fetches a 4-byte chunk of memory and the CPU just knows that the first byte needs to go in the lowest byte of %EAX and working towards the highest byte that receives the fourth byte.

Comment: With that order, mov will take the first 4 bytes from right to left? Like dcba?
01 (a) 00 (b) | 00 (c) 00 (d)

Comment: @Mr.Sir: It does a 4-byte little-endian load, so the first byte ends up at the bottom of the register (`%al`), the last (highest address) byte ends up at the top.  e.g. `.byte 0x12, 0x34, 0x56, 0x78` is the same thing as `.long 0x78563412`.  Or `shrl $8, x` will move each byte to a lower address, shifting in a zero byte, because right shifts move bits towards the LSB, which is in the lowest-address byte on a little-endian machine.